# Use and the meaning of the word EPISTEMIC!

Tags: meaning, meaning-in-context

Can you guys explain the meaning of the word epistemic and the use of it in a sentence? I cannot relate the meaning that I found to the sentences:

> Epistemic - relating to knowledge or to the degree of its validation.

The sentence that I cannot make sense of with the above mentioned definition:

> The Black Swan is the result of collective and individual epistemic limitations, mostly confidence in knowledge.

Comment: Please [edit] your question to include the definitions you found, and what you understand of them. Thanks for improving the question's reference value and making it more answerable!

Comment: I edited it ,please be kind enough to take a look.thanks :)

Comment: I once saw an image macro of two black swans, captioned "We're in ur antipodez, invalidating ur empirical inductionizm". Laughed my butt off. Can't find it now :(

Comment: @DanBron http://farm2.static.flickr.com/1208/530746651_461072b105_m.jpg

Comment: @DanBron Hey can you explain what "We're in ur antipodez, invalidating ur empirical inductionizm" means :)

Comment: @Razor1692 That has a lot more to do with epistemology than English ("what is knowledge?"). If you're interested in a deeper explanation, maybe you'd like to ask over on [Philosophy.se]?

Comment: @DanBron http://philosophy.stackexchange.com/questions/28484/explanation-of-inductive-empiricism :)

Comment: @Razor1692 Nice! But just like on ELL, questions on Philosophy.se are expected to carry details and context; lacking that, they risk closure. I've gone ahead edited in the background for you there, but it won't show up until you approve my edit. Until then, your question is likely to be poorly-received (it already garnered an instant downvote from someone; I applied an upvote to counter that and avoid the bandwagon effect).

Comment: @Razor1692 Key concepts: [Antipodes](http://dictionary.cambridge.org/us/dictionary/english/the-antipodes) is a way of referring to ​Australia and New Zealand by ​people ​living in the ​northern hemisphere; [Inductive reasoning](http://www.livescience.com/21569-deduction-vs-induction.html) makes broad generalizations from specific observations; [Empiricism](http://www.philosophybasics.com/branch_empiricism.html) is the theory that the origin of all knowledge is sense experience. To understand how those relate to each other, see this [article](http://prevos.net/humanities/philosophy/induction).

Comment: @Razor1692 From the article linked above: "Millions of swans have been observed and all of them were white, therefore by induction the statement ‘all swans are white’ is true... The conclusion that ‘all swans are white’ was, until Dutch explorer Willem de Vlamingh in 1697 was the first European to see a black swan in Australia, considered a fact. De Vlamingh thus falsified the previously considered universal truth that all swans are white."

Answer (score 6, accepted):

*Epistemic* comes from the Greek *epistḗmē* (ἐπιστήμη), meaning 'knowledge' or 'understanding'. It's used primarily in philosophy (including the field, [Epistemology](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Epistemology), that bears its name) as an adjective meaning "related to the abstract concept of knowledge or knowability".

An *epistemic limitation*, then, is a limitation relating to knowledge or knowability. An individual epistemic limitation would be a limitation of the ability of a given individual to know things, and a collective epistemic limitation is a limit on the knowledge of a *society*, or of *all* people.

A full discussion of [the Black Swan Theory](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Black_swan_theory) is beyond the scope of this answer. It is sufficient for our purposes to know that it deals with *events that are very difficult or impossible to predict*. The sentence is saying that its subject arises because of the limits of what individuals and societies *know* or *can know*, and that this is why it is difficult to predict.

Comment: Thanks a lot :D .I started reading the book Black Swan by Nasseem Taleb.Its brilliant.Have you read it ?